# com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error

Tags: android, aapt

issue：Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details

this my build.grade:

```
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = "27.0.1"
minSdkVersion = 19
targetSdkVersion = 26
versionCode = 1
versionName = "1.0"
```

and I have tried  'gradle.properies--tandroid.enableAapt2 = false' but it don't work.

help

Comment: `compileSdkVersion = 27` . show build.gradle

Comment: I tried, but I doesn't work. thanks,
project.ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.1"

    minSdkVersion = 19
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    abortOnLintError = false
    checkLintRelease = false
    useJack = false
    abortOnLintError = false
    javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8


}

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

Comment: It means one of your files is either corrupted (png) or ill-formed (xml file). Go to the Teminal window in your Android Studio and run "gradlew clean assembleRelease". Edit the question to include the output and I can help you find the reason for the failure.